# convert the array to the correct form

Tags: php, arrays, csv

After converting the file

```
$rows = array_map('trim', file($lines1));
foreach ($rows as $key => $value) {
  $params = array_map('trim', explode(';', $value));
}
```

an array of the following type is obtained, which is contained in a variable:

```
Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 1 [2] => 2 [3] => i need this [4] => 4 [5] => 5 [6] => 6 [7] => 7 [8] => 8 [9] => 9 [10] => 10 [11] => 11 [12] => 12 [13] => 13 [14] => 14 )
Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 1 [2] => 2 [3] => i need this [4] => 4 [5] => 5 [6] => 6 [7] => 7 [8] => 8 [9] => 9 [10] => 10 [11] => 11 [12] => 12 [13] => 13 [14] => 14 )
etc...
```

how can you combine these arrays and put the values with the key = 3 into separate variables.
View:

```
Array ( [0] => i need this [1] => i need this and etc...
```

Comment: _"an array of the following type is obtained"_ - not _an_ array - _multiple_ arrays. You overwrite $params in each iteration. Instead of doing that, _add_ new elements to it (so that you actually get a two-dimensional array), and then simply use `array_column`.

Comment: And btw., this looks like an attempt to read CSV data - which is something you should really rather be using `fgetcsv` for in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$range = range(1, 100);
$result = array_combine($range, $range);
```

check [array_combine](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)

Comment: but I don't know the exact range for "range", bcz "count" does not count the total number of arrays in a variable, but the total number of elements in one array. There are always 15 of them

Comment: that was just an example!! to get a sample range array:- like [1,2,3...100], with index starting with zero. array_combine($range, $range) - it will combine 2 array's value and make it one. like [0=>3] , [ 0=>4] = [3=>4]

Comment: I believe you have an array index starting with zero, but you want make its key same as value!!  you have mentioned- **i need this**

Comment: Thank you very much, I suffered, and went a little different way. But "array_combine" helped

Comment: Welcome!! There are many such inbuilt functions, just need to explore. :) cheers